# centering span txt using css , issue with double digits

Tags: css

Ok this is quite a weird question.

I cannot for the life of me center this span within the div.
So I have positioned it.

However, what I want is to center the blue numbers exactly within the div. Trouble is, when the numbers change to 10, it shifts to the right a tad.
Had a fellow Stacker, helping me with the js, just need some help with alignment within css now.

Im not sure if you can absolutely centre a counter that centers a single number, and the double digit number is centered too.

Dont make sense ?

K link: [Test Page](http://sitehelp.com.au/demos/countup/version3.html)

Css ( i know its not centered for span element **timer** but it needs to be centered.

Cant get Stack to display code correctly, please check source of the link

Any suggestions on centering the NUMBERS, so that they are dead horizontal center. AND that when number jumps to 10 it doesnt shift to the right or left ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the absolute positioning, add `text-align: center` to the div, add a top margin to the span to center it vertically.

```
.content {
  text-align: center;
}

.timer{
  position: static;
}
```

You don't need the `position: static` but I added it because you had it on `absolute` on your page.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the "top", "left" and "position" properties from the ".timer" element and add "text-align: center" to the ".content" element.
CSS:

```
.content {
    height:140px; 
    width:240px; 
    border-color: #51505b; 
    border-style:solid; 
    border-width:1px; 
    left:500px;
    position:relative;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px; -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    text-align: center;
}
.timer {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:5em;
    color: #398fe8;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}
.msg {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    color: #51505b;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="content">
    <span class="timer">10</span>
    <br>
    <span class="msg"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: nope, tried that. Its something to do with the span class for some reason, itr dont like it